# Using angular inside Aspx page

Tags: asp.net, angular

Scenario: Use an angular app inside an aspx page.

Issue: Aspx page has some scripts placed in an asset folder in one place, and angular's code is placed inside "Areas/Navigation/www". When I build the code using  `ng build --prod --base-href Areas/Navigation/View/www/`, it generates the single index file.

I used all the js file reference in my aspx page

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Areas/Navigation/View/www/runtime.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Areas/Navigation/View/www/es2015-polyfills.js" nomodule></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Areas/Navigation/View/www/polyfills.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Areas/Navigation/View/www/styles.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Areas/Navigation/View/www/vendor.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Areas/Navigation/View/www/main.js"></script>
<base href="Areas/Navigation/View/www/" />
....
<app-navigation></app-navigation>
```

But when i run the application, It's expecting my aspx js/css files to be inside `Areas/Navigation/View/www/`. How can I solve his?

**Update #1:**

I tried using `ng build`, the angular app is rendered in the aspx project but the fonts and transalation file is not loaded.

[image]

Actually the en-US.json and the fonts resides in `https://localhost:44301/Areas/Navigation/View/www`

**Update #2:**

The fonts are actually from an node package. Its not my font but a third party node package which uses these fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially root will be empty so you need to give the parent root path in root and source root will be your source folder

Something like this:

```
"NavBar": {
"root": "/path-to-your-aspx-project/",
"sourceRoot": "src",
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to build without specific your base href like this

```
ng build --prod
```

I think you dont need to specific base href because you already include all the script in your aspx view

Comment: Thanks for the response, this did solve me partially, now the app is loaded but not the fonts and the translation file. Please see my updated questions. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you move those asset into folder that serve static asset. In .net core we have wwwroot folder and user can access all of the assets in that folder. I'm not sure about aspx

Comment: How to move? In angular.json it's set to src folder and www folder

Comment: You can move all assets file into your angular assets folder locate in src/assets or move to www folder in asp.net

Comment: manually? No man, this code will be pushed to jenkins which automates the installation process. It should be via code. :(